# what is 'buddy' that mentioned a lot in kernel/sched/fair.c ?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

Im going over the code of fair.c(kernel 3.14 ) [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c?v=3.14) (for a school project) and I see alot of times the word **buddy** . Im trying to figure out what is it ??

I found [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/520857/) article about **Small task packing** which mentions 'buddy' here :

> Vincent's patch assigns a "buddy" to each CPU at system initialization time. Arguably "buddy" is the wrong term to use, since the relationship is a one-way affair; a CPU can dump small tasks onto its buddy (and only onto the buddy), but said buddy cannot reciprocate.

But from the context in fair.c file I cant see how is that connected .

If somebody can shed some light on this vague subject

thanks!

Comment: As far as I understand this terminology, a `buddy` is worker kernel thread describing object.

Comment: @SergeyKanaev You got it wrong. In this context the `buddy` term means some CPU core, related to other CPUs in a way that some small tasks can be migrated from those CPUs to their **pack buddy CPU**. Of course, if I understood it correctly from **Vincent's patch** description, which mentioned article is referring to.